# Receiving Push Notification from FCM on app terminated

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM onbackgroundmessage not working on app terminated even though I (think) met all the conditions specified in the documentation.
Here's a sample message being sent

```
<?php
    function sendNotification(){
        $server_token="AAAAksZAlDc:APA91bGLAfguJLdXmz65F-server token";
        $headers=array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: key=$server_token");
    
        $url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        $ch= curl_init($url);
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $kita=time();
        $uid="dELAY-CRRm6z4ICpQP user  token";
        //$post_data= array("to"=> "$uid", "notification"=> array("title"=> "server title", "body"=>"Body from the server"));
        $kita= date("jS F Y h:i:a", time());
        $post_data= array("to"=> "/topics/sample_topic", "notification"=> array("title"=> "server title at $kita" , "body"=>"Body from the server"));
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $resp= curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo "<p>Response is $resp</p>";
    }
    sendNotification();
?>
```

Then waiting for the notification in my flutter app

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(fcmBGMsgs);
Future<void> fcmBGMsgs(remoteMessage){
  //defined outside every class
}
```

Kindly share if you have a sample working demo

Comment: did you subscribe from the app to the topic ?

Comment: Yes, I have done all that subscription and gotten token for device

Comment: Good, also did you try sending notifications from firebase console ?